# AngularJS not displaying json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've been stuck for some time now trying to display `JSON` data in a table with **AngularJS 1.6.9**.

> Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Een eenvoudige service</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="service.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<div ng-app="mijnApp" ng-controller="mijnController">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in personen">
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{x.City}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

> Here is my JavaScript:

```
var App = angular.module('mijnApp', []);
App.controller('mijnController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("personen.json").then(function(response) {
        $scope.personen = response.data;
    });
});
```

> Small example of my json file:

```
{
    "records": [{
        "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "City": "Berlin",
        "Country": "Germany"
    }, {
        "Name": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
        "City": "México D.F.",
        "Country": "Mexico"
    }]
}
```

I've tried multiple methods and the result is always the same - empty table.

How can I resolved this issue? Please help me for the same issue.

Comment: $scope.personen

Comment: unwrap `"records"` -> `<tr ng-repeat="x in personen.records">`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in personen.records">
            <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{x.City}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: using this approach am getting data displayed but also I get this error `OrderDeatilsComponent.html:16 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the records from response. use `x in personen.records` or set de personen in the http response like this `$scope.personen = response.data.records;`

I prefer the second option personally.

Answer (score -1):

This will help

```
$.ajax({ 
    url : "personen.json", 
    dataType : 'JSON', 
    success : function(data) { 
        $scope.personen = data;
    }, 
    error : function(error) { 
        console.log( "error occurred." );     
    }
});
```

**HTML** use this to view the records.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="record in personen.records">
       <td> {{record.Name}} </td>
       <td> {{record.City}} </td>
       <td> {{record.Country}} </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @oma pointing to the hardcoded json, returns only the data except the status and anything else. It works for me and I am still using it. Please upvote

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't noticed that you changed the angular `$http` call to `ajax` one, sry my bad, but still not solve his issue, because he forgot to use another object(records) from the response json.

Comment: this will not solve his issue, is not a good answer after all :|

Comment: @oma the whole object is returned into **$scope.personen** and then using **personen.records** in html angularjs, successfully fetches the records. What's the problem?

Comment: upvoted, but pls remove your 2 code snippets, they are useless to solve his issue... and if you always edit your answer is disturbing.. because i put a comment that your initial code is irrelevant as answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168842/discussion-between-badshah-tracker-and-oma).